# How to create a seamless loop in AE without a dissolve or crossfade?

Tags: after-effects

I am a beginner AE user and a much more proficient Ps user.  Can I somehow duplicate the comp and lower opacity of the top one and move the bottom one on the timeline to manually line up frames so that I can find a great start and end of the loop ( these are videos of people for example)?  I am willing to go any extra mile so that there is no "jump" whatsoever.  Can I use a transform tool to line them up?  I just have no idea how to do this and would love some advice.  I would think there would be a tried and true way to create a true seamless loop with no jump whatsoever or evidence of a cross fade?

Thank you for taking the time to answer!  Lisa

Comment: an example of the frames you're using would help us to answer

Comment: It would entirely depend on the content of the shot whether you get a seamless loop or not. Unless you want to ping-pong the shot backwards and forwards.